# Disable the lock screen when specific apps are active?

Tags: lock-screens

I'm looking for a way to disable the lock screen when specified apps are active. It's annoying when the screen times out and I have to swipe the lock screen to start a new [pomodoro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.artifix.pomodroido.free&hl=en) or use the calculator.

I don't want to disable the lock screen entirely because I don't want my phone to activate when it's in my pocket. And I don't want to disable screen timeout, because I want to conserve the battery. I tried replacing the lock screen with [PocketLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pajayo.pocketlock&hl=en), which uses the proximity sensor to turn off the phone when it's in my pocket, but I found its behavior too inconsistent.

My phone is a Samsung Transform Ultra with Android 2.3.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can e.g. be realized using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (in fact, I'm even using it that way for "prolonged screen timeout" with reading apps):

- **Condition:** App (opens a popup to select one ore multiple apps, chose the ones you want to act upon)
- **Task:**

  - Keyguard (disable)
  - Display -> Timeout (optionally increase display timeout)

The tasks would be executed as soon as one of the selected apps is running in foreground, and reverted to what it was before as soon as the condition no longer is met.

<sup>Note: I know that *Tasker* doesn't come cheap (~5 bucks), but it's worth every cent. To "try before buy", visit its homepage, where you can download a 7-day-trial.</sup>